# トップレベルで for...は使わないのが望ましいのか？

Tags: javascript

あらためて美しいJavaScriptを書きたいなと思い、JSLintを使い始めました
下記をJSLintにかけたとき

```
var myArr = [1,2,3];
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) {
    //
}
```

> ## 1 Unexpected 'for' at top level.
>
> for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) { // Line 2, Pos 1
>
> ## 2 Unexpected 'var'.
>
> for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) { // Line 2, Pos 6

と評価されます。まぁJSLintが絶対とはおもいませんが・・・

- トップレベルでFORは使わないほうがよいのでしょうか？
- i の宣言は前もって宣言しておいたほうが良いのでしょうか？

あるいは、JSLintのポリシーについて解説などあるリソースなどございましたら、ご教授くださいませ。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@argus さんの回答を見るかぎり、for文そのものの使用についてはなんとも…なのですが、

- *i の宣言は前もって宣言しておいたほうが良いのでしょうか？*

これ(forの中でvarを使うこと)については、かなりはっきりと説明できる危険性があります。

それはJavaScriptのローカル変数のスコープは関数/クロージャ単位であって、(他の似た文法の言語のような)ブロック単位ではない、という点です。

```
    var i = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        //
    }
    alert(i); //->10
```

他の言語に慣れた方だと、forの中でvar付きで宣言された`i`はその外側の`i`とは別物で、外側の`i`はfor文の実行前後で値が変化しないように思われる方が多いのですが、実際にはforの外側の`i`とfor内にvar付きで使われている`i`は同じ変数をさしており、alert等で確認すればすぐにわかりますが、for文の実行結果後の値が表示されます。

そのような、スコープを間違えそうなvarの使い方すべてにJSLintが警告を出してくれるかどうかは知らないのですが、for-varはつい勘違いする人が多そうなので、一律警告を出してくるのには意味があると思います。(まぁ、私はスコープのことをわかっててもよくこの書き方をするので、JSLintは使わないと思いますが…。)

Comment: ES2015で追加された `let` はブロックスコープを持ち、`for` のようにブロックを伴うステートメントで使えばそのブロック内部に限定されるのですが、これでもJSLintでは警告出るようですね。

Comment: だとすると「作者の趣味」感が漂いますね。for自体を基本禁止にしちゃったんで、比較的新しい仕様に突っ込んだ実装をする気がないと言うのもありそうですが。

Comment: i のスコープについてはそういやあまり気を使っていないことに気が付きました。
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 5):

JSLint の [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) を眺めてみたのですが、非常に厳しいですね。デフォルトでは `for statement` を使っただけで警告が表示されてしまいます。まずは `Tolerate` の `for statement` にチェックを入れて、以下の様に書く必要があります。

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];

function test() {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) {
        //
    }
}
```

ただ、こうしても `Empty block.` と言われます。

`for statement` については [JSLint: Help](http://jslint.com/help.html) に以下の記述があります。

> **Tolerate for statement**
>   true if the for statement should be allowed. It is almost always better to use the array methods instead.

ソースコードと上記のヘルプを眺める限り、JSLint の作者である Douglas Crockford さんの**単なる好み**なんじゃないかと思いますけど。

Comment: [本家SOでの回答](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30518734/2818869)で[作者による講演](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo36MrBfTk4&feature=youtu.be&t=21m30s)が紹介されていましたが、結局「`forEach()` や `map()` で代用できるのだから、私はもうforを使わないことにした」としか言ってないんですよねえ・・・。